# Mock up InboundJaxrsResponse

Tags: java, unit-testing, jax-rs

For testing I want to create a mockup of `InboundJaxrsResponse`, or any class extending `javax.ws.rs.core.Response` and implementing `readEntity()` methods. This proves rather difficult. Is there a library ready to do it, or is there a way I don't see? My searches don't turn out anything.

Answer (score 3):

In [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25844646/mock-or-build-a-jersey-inboundjaxrsresponse) you see an example of using Mockito to mock the readEntity() call:

```
Response response = mock(Response.class);
when(response.readEntity(InputStream.class)).thenReturn(ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("example_response.xml");
```

Hope this helps, and if not, can you explain what problems you run into?