# Mock or build a Jersey InboundJaxrsResponse

Tags: java, unit-testing, jersey, java-ee-7, jersey-client

I'm fairly new developing jersey client, and has run into some problems with some testing.
First off all I maybe should mention that my application is all client side, no server side stuff at all.

My problem is that I would like to create a `Response` object of instance `InboundJaxrsResponse`, so far I've tried to achieve this by mocking a `Response` using `Mockito` and `ResponseBuilder.build()`

Using Mockito:

```
Response response = mock(Response.class);
when(response.readEntity(InputStream.class))
    .thenReturn(ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("example_response.xml");
```

this works fine, when I read out the entity of the response with `response.readEntity(InputStream.class)`
I get the entity as expected. However I need to read the entity from the response several times. in order to achieve this I use `response.bufferEntity()` before I read out the entity. The first time I read the entity all works fine, but the second time I get an exception `I/O stream closed`... 
Well I figured out mocking the method `bufferEntity` as well like following:

```
Response response = mock(Response.class);
when(response.bufferEntity()).thenCallRealMethod();
when(response.readEntity(InputStream.class))
    .thenReturn(ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("example_response.xml");
```

But this only results in a Error being thrown upon calling `bufferEntity()`, this is because `bufferEntity()` of `Response` is `abstract`.

My other attempt is by using `ResponseBuilder.build()` like following:

```
ResponseBuilder responseBuilder = Response.accepted(ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("example_response.xml"));
Response response = responseBuilder.build();
```

This declaration is fine and by debugging my response I can see that it got correct entity and so on. But this time when I call `response.bufferEntity()` I get an exception thrown saying that the operation is illegal for an `OutboundJaxrsResponse` so by building a response in this way resulting in wrong instance of `Response.class`:

So this ends up in three questions.

1. Is this the way at all to mock/build objects of this types for testing?
2. Is there a way to mock a inbound response?
3. Is there a way to instead of creating a instance of `OutboundJaxrsResponse` with `ResponseBuilder.build()` creating a instance of `InboundJaxrsResponse`, or at least casting/converting an instance of `OutboundJaxrsResponse` to an instance of `OutboundJaxrsResponse`?

Comment: This could help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19557672/unable-to-mock-glassfish-jersey-client-response-object

Answer (score 5):

I solved in this way:

```
@Spy Response response;

...

// for assignments in code under testing:
doReturn( response ).when( dwConnector ).getResource( anyString() );

// for entity and response status reading:
doReturn( "{a:1}".getBytes() ).when( response ).readEntity( byte[].class );
doReturn( 200 ).when( response ).getStatus();
```